# Filter Gtest based on two filters

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have multiple GTests. I would like to run only some of them based on two filters. For example, I want to run all UI properties tests. Something like: --gtest_filter=*Properties* and --gtest_filter=*UI*. I would like to use both filters in the same run. 
I could not find the syntax for passing 2 filters at the same time.
I read [this](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests), I would like to do something like the 3rd example - *./foo_test --gtest_filter=*Null*:*Constructor* Runs any test whose full name contains either "Null" or "Constructor"*, but to run any test whose full name contains **both** "Null" **and** "Constructor".
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you specify multiple filters:

```
 --gtest_filter=*Properties*:*UI*
```

EDIT:
In case you want both words to be included in the filter, you can use this:

```
--gtest_filter=*Properties*UI*:*UI*Properties*
```

Comment: according to link I posted this is for specifying one of the multiple filters. I would like both.

Comment: @eskadi This is how you specify both filters. Have you tried it before commenting here?

Comment: @eskadi I now see that you've edited the question. Now it is clear what you want. Next time, please try to provide a clear question right away to avoid situations like this.

Comment: You can also do negative filters with a minus like this `--gtest_filter=*UI*:-*DB*`